# Hyperledger Composer Channels concepts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been building an application in hyperledger composer.
All the tutorials I find related to hyperledger fabrics talks a lot about Orderers, Channels, Peers, Ledger etc. But none of the hyperledger composer tutorial relates the concepts of Asset, transaction or Participants to those.

For instance, hyperledger composer supports only a single channel, then how is the privacy of a transaction maintained there? Is it through the permission.acl file?

Also relating to the famous Vehicle lifecycle network.

1. Will each of those manufacturer be an organization(having several peers within it) in a blockchain network?
2. Do all the manufactures needs to host a peer(containing both the ledger and chaincode)?
3. Does the regulator body also need a peer?

Please help me understanding it clearly.

Comment: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/17549928

Answer (score 1):

See here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/key-concepts for Concepts and here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction for an Intro to Hyperledger Composer and a slidedeck on Composer concepts can be found here -> https://www.slideshare.net/MattLucas3/blockchain-composed-v207

1. Manufacturer will be a member organisation of the blockchain network
2. Its likely a Manufacturer will want to host it, or have it hosted as a major party. Its also possible that an organisation doesn't stand up any infrastructure and relies on a portal into the blockchain if it is agreed it should have an interest, by the consortium that stand up the blockchain network. Same applies for the Regulator in that respect.

Comment: For instance, hyperledger composer supports only a single channel, then how is the privacy of a transaction maintained there? Is it through the permission.acl file?

Comment: Hi @Paul Does the permission.acl file eliminates the need of another channel in hyperledger composer?

Comment: hi there, Composer manages the real-time access to data resources / instances through ACLs yes (ie transactions, assets or indeed participant registries,  all stored on the blockchain). The ACLs are effectively ringfencing access in the business network itself (deployed as a smart contract to the blockchain) through ACLs. These are structured security authorization rules/access control lists for the business network, deployed on that Fabric channel (ie  private to the member Orgs that joined the channel). 'Participants' (real people) in the biz network are governed by the implemented ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the concept of private channels is a feature of Hyperledger fabric and isn't available in the composer framework. But, to achieve the privacy of transaction that you are talking about you can use the ACL rules effectively. You can control who sees which transaction by defining rules in the acl file and applying them on the Historian record that contains all the transactions.

You must read about historian record (Will prove to be very useful while writing the acl for controlling transaction records): https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/historian.html

Also, For data privatization in hyperledger composer there are certain practices and ways that will prove to be very useful. Go through this article: https://medium.com/coinmonks/implementing-data-privatization-within-hyperledger-composer-2bc99a11c344

Now, about the second part of your questions- Hyperledger composer doesn't involves all those endorsing peers, committing peers endorsing policy and such. In hyperledger composer when we create the rest server and the angular application and all the transactions are recorded from a single identity. For achieving a multi-user model for production using composer we can use the multi-user mode of the composer rest server and the authentication feature of the same. This helps in creating different identities/wallet for different users and then the transactions are recorded from those respective wallets.